# Mac Catalyst and iOS 13.5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, mac-catalyst

I am currently getting a weird warning from Xcode 11.5 (I'm using the release version):

> The Mac Catalyst deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 13.5, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 13.1 to 13.4.99.

I did a web search and haven't seen this message mentioned by anybody.

Now, I could set my deployment back to iOS 13.0 (I'm not using any special features in iOS 13.5 in my project), but was wondering why this particular warning is being issued? Certainly, Apple has not decided to discontinue support for Mac Catalyst, has it?

Comment: I am using 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' 13. Mac Catalyst is working fine. What you want to know can you explain to me in details? If I am setting it 13, the app is working fine on MacOS 10.15.5  and iOS 13.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Mac Catalyst deployment target 13.5 is not supported yet. Lower value should be fine.