# macOS Simulator deployment target set to 13.5, but the range of supported deployment target version for this platform is from 13.1 to 13.4.999

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, mac-catalyst

I'm getting this warning message in Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c)

> The Mac Catalyst deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 13.5, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 13.1 to 13.4.99. (in target 'Food Tracker' from project 'Food Tracker')

[the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nmwA.png)

My deployment target is for a universal binary

[my deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQJrF.png)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118264/mac-catalyst-and-ios-13-5. There's really no point repeating it; if it gets solved there, it is by definition solved everywhere.

Comment: Hi @matt. No I am not using any pods cocoa or otherwise, just plain old Xcode

Comment: @matt Oh I see. Sorry for the duplicate question...it didn't show up in the autofill section when I wrote it. I will follow that thread for any updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. Just decrease your iOS Deployment Target in the Build Settings to lower the Mac Catalyst deployment target.
Obviously you have selected "Mac" in the Deployment Info of your target and the current Xcode version does not support Mac Catalyst deployment target 13.5.